# Testing Twilio SMS API ON POSTMAN ERROR 21604 "A 'To' phone number is required.",

Tags: postman, twilio-api

I am getting error 21604 on postman while testing twilio sms api

It says

> to' phone number is required.

where as I have put a validated phone number from twilio.

I am using trial account. What can be done? How to debug?

Comment: Please share the code you are using. You can obfuscate/change any personal details.

Comment: if you are using PHP it is super easy to use the twilio package.                            
  // Send an SMS using Twilio's REST API and PHP
<?php
$sid = "ACXXXXXX"; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
$token = "YYYYYY"; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
$message = $client->messages->create(
  '8881231234', // Text this number
  [
    'from' => '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
    'body' => 'Hello from Twilio!'
  ]
);

print $message->sid;

Answer (score 1):

The Twilio API only accepts requests with the body formatted as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

You can also reference
[Using Twilio to send Messages via POST, but will not accept the body as JSON or XML, only plain parameters of To, From and Body works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64218813/using-twilio-to-send-messages-via-post-but-will-not-accept-the-body-as-json-or/64219815#64219815)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Post method on url :

> **[https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account](https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%7BAccount) SID}/Messages.json**

with basic authentication where username:Account SID & password:Auth Token
and the parameter in body->x-www-form-urlencoded in this form
From:+1330679****
Body:This is twilio test
To:+91878971****

Comment: Can you format this post so it is a little more clear what the request params are?