# HTTP Functions for SQL (QSYS2) on the IBM i in RPGLE to send a message via Twilio

Tags: twilio, http-post, rpgle

I am trying to use the new HTTP Functions for SQL (QSYS2) on the IBM i in RPGLE to send a message via Twilio. I have looked up the examples and have used the same code to try to send a text through my Twilio account, but no matter what i send i get back :

{"code": 21604, "message": "A 'To' phone number is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604", "status": 400}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Examples of Code I have tried:

1)

```
     dcl-s account_Sid varchar(40);
       dcl-s auth_Token varchar(40);
       dcl-s url varchar(2000);
       dcl-s request varchar(2000);
       dcl-s response varchar(5000);
       dcl-s options varchar(1000);
       
 exec sql
         values json_object(
         'body' value 'This is a test text',
           'from' value '+194xxxxxxxx',
           'to' value '+185xxxxxxxx')
         into :request;



       url='https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+account_sid+'/Messages.json';

       options='{"basicAuth":"'+account_sid+','+auth_token+'",'+
               '"header":"content-type,application/x-www-form-urlencode"}';

       exec sql
         values QSYS2.HTTP_POST(:url, :request, :options)
         into :response;
```

> request set to {"body":"This is a test ext","from":"+194XXXXXXXX","to":"+18XXXXXXXXX"}

2. I even tried to hard code everything

```
    exec sql
           qsys2.http_post(
            'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json', CAST(
                'To=185XXXXXXXX' CONCAT '&From=194XXXXXXXX' CONCAT '&Body=This is a test' AS VARCHAR(855)),
            '{"basicAuth":"ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,f6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
             "header":"content-type,application/x-www-form-urlencode"}');
```

Comment: did you try with `Content-Type: application/json` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` (with a d at the end) ?

Comment: do you need a colon (:) instead of comma between account_sid and auth_token.  Looking at there docs that looks like what they want.

Comment: I tried with both urlencode as well as urlencoded and got the same result. I also tried with application/json and stll no luck.

Comment: It looks like you are setting the content type correctly as `application/x-www-form-urlencode` but you are formatting the data as JSON? Also in your hardcoded version you are missing the `+` at the start of a phone number, but also should be url encoded (as should the spaces in the body of the message).

Comment: just curious if it was solved. Have you tried philnash suggestions? Have you seen this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64218813/using-twilio-to-send-messages-via-post-but-will-not-accept-the-body-as-json-or?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I recently took this same task on and finally achieved success by ensuring my header contains... "sslTolerate":"true"

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that you need "+" in front of both the "to" and "from" phone numbers? My script has them. ie: &From=+1937

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."